# Number of natural numbers with an odd sum of number of divisors till that number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of natural numbers $n<2023$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_0(i)$ is odd, where $\sigma_0(x)$ denotes the number of divisors of $x$.

First, I know that $\sigma_0(x) = (n_1 +1)(n_2 +1)(n_3+1)\dots$ where $x = p_1^{n_1}\cdot p_2^{n_2} \cdot p_3^{n_3}\dots$ with all $p$ being primes.

Hence, it can be observed that $\sigma_0(x)$ is odd if $x$ is a perfect square.

Also, $\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_0(i)$ is odd if there are an odd number of odd terms in $\sigma_0(1)+\sigma_0(2) + \dots + \sigma_0(n)$. In other terms, that means there must be an odd number of perfect squares from $1$ till $n$.

So, the values of possible $n$ that satisfy the given constraint are: $1,2,3,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,25,26,\dots$ Now I am having some difficulty in counting this till $2022$.

We need to remove all numbers between even squares and the next square, and including the even square to find the number of values till $2022$.

I know that $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ but I always get errors in my count. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of errors?  It sounds like you're almost there.

Comment: My count is off by $3$, and I think it is because of some error in my method counting.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?  I know a lot of contest problems include the current year.

Comment: It is from a local school competition. But on earlier accounts I have found their problems plagiarized from national competitions, so it could have been asked in other contests too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be the number of numbers between an odd square and an even square. Writing this as a summation, we get:

$\sum_{i=1}^{22}((2n)^2-(2n-1)^2)$

This counts all such numbers up to $44^2$, which does the job. Now to solve the summation,

$\sum_{i=1}^{22}((2n)^2-(2n-1)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{22}(4n-1)=4\sum_{i=1}^{22}n-\sum_{i=1}^{22}1$

This can be solved using the formula for the sum of first $n$ natural numbers, $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Thus, we get,
$4\sum_{i=1}^{22}n-\sum_{i=1}^{22}1=4\times \frac{22\times 23}{2}-22=1012-22=990$.

Also, just curious about the source of this problem as it was also there in IOQM 2023, where they asked for the sum of its digits.